# Can we print Calculated field in Sharepoint List Header using JSON?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list-form, json-formatting

I have a calculated field based on other multiple columns. I want to show the value of it in Header part. When I am using  the same in JSON, it says "Can not read property value of Null". However I do not have any null value in  the status column.

Comment: It's hard to tell what you're doing without seeing the JSON itself. One thing to keep in mind, however, is that list formatting requires the fields you want to reference to be part of the view (unlike calculated columns). So if you are referencing a column (`[$SomeField]`) and it isn't part of the view, the value will be null.

Answer (score 0):

Per my knowledge, you cannot customize list header with JSON formatting. All we can do is to hide column header.